# Why am I unable to tokenize or import tokenize from nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am receiving the below ImportError:

```
     1 import nltk
---->2 from nltk.tokenize import tokenize
     3 import re

ImportError: cannot import name 'tokenize' from 'nltk.tokenize'
```

Comment: try from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import like this:
`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow to take a look at all available methods of the library.

```
import nltk.tokenize

dir(nltk.tokenize)
```

As you will see there is no `tokenize` and that is the reason of error occurrence.

```
# to get more information about
help(nltk.tokenize)
```